# Having trouble understanding Apache's documentation of

Tags: java, apache

I am having trouble understanding what UriHttpRequestHandlerMapper as written about in the documentation [here](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-4.3.x/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/protocol/UriHttpRequestHandlerMapper.html).

The documentation says that it:

> Maintains a map of HTTP request handlers keyed by a request URI
>   pattern.  Patterns may have three formats:
>   `*`
>   `*<uri>`
>   `<uri>*`

It doesn't explain what these patterns actually mean.
What do the stars do? How do you actually use this?

I have not been able to find any snippets on the internet.

Comment: `*` represents wildcard entries . (i.e) other than uri's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `*` means match any request
2. `*<uri>` means match any request that ends with what is specified, e.g. `*.jpg`
3. `<uri>*` means match any request that starts with what is
   specified, e.g. `http://host/application/*`

Comment: Thanks. so what does this mean? If I say `urihttpreqmapper.register("*.jpg", new HttpRequestHandler())` then when the server hear's a request of something like `www.boo.com/p.jpg` it will handle it with the `new Handler`? But looking at the docs, `new Handler` still requires `requests`, `responses` etc. Where do all these come from?

Comment: HttpRequestHandler is an interface; you create one that contains your code to actually respond to a request--the request, response and context will be passed into your `handle()` method by apache

Comment: Ah.. ok it seems it gets executed by an `HttpService` objects [doc](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-4.2.x/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/protocol/HttpService.html)